# Which limits to draw for speculations in an scientific publication?

Tags: publications, research-process, writing

Let's take an example from geology.

I describe an area (A) using a topographic map not really well detailed (50m of resolution). In this area, I study variably-sized shapes of geologic structures (e.g., volcanoes). I have also from A, an area B that is way more detailed (1m-resolution) and it has been described by direct observations (on the field).
Now, I want to do analyzes of structures within A, given the knowledge from B, and check if similar structures of B are observable in the entire area A (not covered by B) so that the observation is extrapolated over the low-resolution data. I make a description of this in a little section of a paper.

The description is important to make probabilistic estimates. The aim of the paper I have in mind, deals with estimates of (1) where are the wanted structures, and (2) what shape do they have in the entire A.

**Problem:**

I cannot publish all of what has been done in B (yet), but just enough details (some are published already) to make the main structures wanted being characterized in A.

I want to publish the estimates done within A, but by using low-resolution data, which means, discriminating less characterizable structures; they can still be distinguished though.

**Questions:**

By doing (a) extrapolation of descriptions, and (b) general estimates on low-resolution data, should I fear about doing to much "speculations"?

I am more concerned about (a) than (b), because for the latter, the results are debatable and the method used is totally new and worthy for research in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about research in a particular field, not about academia in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legitimacy of such extrapolations is, as far as I know, among the topics studied by statisticians.  If I'm right about that, it would be good to ask a statistician about your extrapolations, both to check how valid they are and also, if they are valid, to get some citable support for their validity.